# How to get category name in Youtube API in ASP.NET4.0 application

Tags: youtube-api, asp.net-4.0

I have implemented You-tube API in asp.net 4.0 application.I can access all other parameter except category.

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(ApplicationName,developerKey,myUserName,myPassword);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + YouTubeID + "");
Video objVideo = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
var desc= objVideo.Description;
var title= objVideo.Title;
var category= ? ;
```

How can i get category?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK that's it.

I found solution on my way.

```
var catValue = objVideo.Tags.ToList<MediaCategory>().FirstOrDefault<MediaCategory>().Value
```